# erorr in My Code

Tags: c#, security

I'm using the following code to apply the caesar cipher algorithm ,
But didn't work well

the code

```
foreach (char t in richTextBox1.Text)
        {
            char encrypted = (char)(t + 3);
            richTextBox2.Text = encrypted.ToString();
        }
```

When the plain text is 'mostafa' return 'd' only this take the last char 
what can i do .

Thanks

Comment: @JustinPihony: Seems users are more desperate than you think ;p

Comment: @leppie - the fruit was just too low hanging :)

Comment: The char value of `a` + 3 would equal `d` your code is doing exactly what it should do. Of course you actually want to use `+=` instead of `=` considering you want to display the entire string instead of the last character in the new string.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
StringBuilder enrypted = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char t in richTextBox1.Text)
{
    encrypted.Append((char)(t + 3));                
}
richTextBox2.Text = encrypted.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (char t in richTextBox1.Text)
{
    char encrypted = (char)(t + 3);
    richTextBox2.Text = encrypted.ToString();
}
```

Because you are assigning the `richTextBox2.Text` to a single character. The last one happens to be the one that gets displayed. Your results aren't cumulative.

You can do something like this instead:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char t in richTextBox1.Text)
{
    char encrypted = (char)(t + 3);
    sb.Append(encrypted);
}
richTextBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
richTextBox2.Text = encrypted.ToString();
```

to

```
richTextBox2.Text += encrypted.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I really like LINQ

```
char[] text = richTextBox1.Text.ToCharArray();
richTextBox2.Text = new String(text.Select(ch => (char)(ch + 3)).ToArray());
```